# how to show the searchResultsController of UISearchController when the searchBar is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMx3N.png)I have to type some words to make the searchResultsController show,but what I want to do is showing the searchResultsController as soon as the searchBar is active.How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is by implementing the UISearchBarDelegate and then implement searchBarShouldBeginEditing.
What you can do then is something like this:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    return false
}
```

Unless the search view controller isn't situated in the tabbar, then you can just tell the navigationController to slide the searchResultsController into view. In the searchResultsController you can tell the searchbar to start editing with:

```
searchbar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Just make sure to be aware from where the user comes from because I'd imagine it might be annoying if it would get called everytime viewDidAppear gets triggered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when I type the searchbar.becomeFirstResponder() in the  searchResultsController,I got a error that 'Use of unresolved identifier 'searchBar',Could you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a searchbar in your searchResultsController?

Comment: I added  a photo in my question,that is what I want to achieve,when I make the searchBar active,it will become the same as the photo.

Comment: Yeah, so just switch to that view when searchBarShouldBeginEditing gets triggered. In any other view with the searchbar, apply the delegate to the UISearchbar and switch it to the searchResultsController as soon as searchBarShouldBeginEditing is called.

Comment: You're welcome. Would appreciate it if you could mark the answer as correct in case someone else has the same issue!